# Any way to easily include multiple Maven artifacts from the same group?

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I have several Java projects that pom.xml to define dependencies. It all works nicely but there's a lot of repetition so I am trying to move duplicate dependencies into a new parent pom file.

Let's say my parent pom.xml has the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Hazelcast dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My child pom.xml has:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This isn't too bad as I'm only adding two artifacts. Is there a way to add the two dependencies with only one entry? I tried the following based on an online post, but it doesn't work but it does give an idea of what I was hoping for:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm also depending on several different Jetty artifacts so I'm trying to see if there's a way to reduce content. I know I can write out each artifact dependency separately in the child pom.xml files but I thought I'd see if there's a way to simplify.

Thanks

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... Welcome to the wonderful world of XML! :-D